# python-m2crypto installation in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu version 20.04.6 on the system but the default python version support was 3.10. After that, I've changed the default python support from 3.10 to 2.7. I'm trying to install the python 2.7 on ubuntu 20.04.6 with some of the sudo commands as:

```
~sudo apt update
~sudo apt upgrade
~sudo apt-get install python2.7 
~sudo apt-get install python-lxml 
~sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto 
~sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

But I'm getting failed at 5th sudo command (~sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto) as it was not getting installed on the system with Ubuntu. Can anyone please suggest me some other steps so that I can installed it?

By taking the reference of "How to install Python2.7 in Ubuntu 20.04" document, I've run the below commands to install Python 2.7:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python2.7-minimal
python2 -V (for checking the installed python verion i.e. 2.7.18)
ls /usr/bin/python* (to check all the installed python version available in Ubuntu)
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python usr/bin/python2 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python usr/bin/python3 2
(Above 2 commands are for changing the default python version)
python -V (to check if Python2.7 becomes the default Python or not)
```